# @Path optional slashes/values in between Jax-Rs

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-rs

I need to have a URL requests like:

- service
- service/1/2////5
- service/1/////5
- service/1/2/3//5
- service/1/2/3/4/5

i did this:

```
@Path("/{corp:([0-9]{1,2})?}{a:/?}{div:([0-9]{1,2})?}{b:/?}{dist :([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2})?}{c:/?}{store:([0-9]{1,4})?}{d:/?}{role:([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,4})?}{e:/?}{group:([0-9]{1,2})?}")
```

in our local server this piece of code works fine, but when we deploy it in the development server, the optional doesn't work at all.

if you request :
service/1////5

the url request will be:
service/1/5

our hunch maybe because of the old jax-rs we're using? or the weblogic doesn't recognize optional slashes? can i use escape characters on @Path?

Comment: What are you deploying to locally and on the dev server?  Why are they different?

Comment: i deployed the code snippet locally, and it is working fine. However when we deployed it via the dev server it is not working as expected. Yes we don't have any idea why it is different. Before I created different methods for different sub-resource hierarchy.

Comment: Are both servers weblogic?  If so, what versions?

Comment: my friend uses 10c, i used 12c and both of us can run the code properly, the dev server i think uses 10c also. My question now, is it possible to have that kind of Path that can omit middle part sub-resources or not?

Comment: 10c - please provide the actual version #.  e.g. 10.3.4, 10.3.5 etc.  12c is an EE6 compliant server so it ships with a JAX-RS runtime.

Comment: The version our dev server (weblogic) is running - 10.3.6

Comment: we noticed that one regex our colleague was using doesn't have the greedy quantifiers, in which we are using it in the new one. (example [0-9]{1,2})